# Getting "No line found" when pulling values from an external file

Tags: java, arrays, random, java.util.scanner

Alright, so I need to grab some strings at random from a file not of a fixed size. So, to do this, I start by counting the lines in the file using a simple while loop. After that, I simply feed that value to a random object and store the ten values I need into the array:

```
int[] select = new int[10];
```

I run into problems however with this code.

```
 String[] value = new String[10];
 for (sel = 0; sel <= 9; sel++){
      int w = select[sel];
      Scanner input = new Scanner(file.txt);      
      for (int q = 0; q <= w; q++){ 
        String bank = input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();
        value[sel] = bank;
      }
```

The code works, but it seems that if the value the code is looking for is too high, (EDIT: Confirmed at over 60) I get the exception:

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

The file in question has over 100 lines, so how would a value of 75 cause this error?

Comment: The inner loop is calling input.nextLine()  twice. Is that on purpose?

Comment: I had thought you needed that to cycle the lines. Guess not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are skipping 1 line and reading the next line every iteration, which means you are moving down 2 lines everytime.

```
String bank = input.nextLine();
input.nextLine();
```

So at 60, it is actually trying to read the 120th line.

Instead, just do as:

```
for (int q = 0; q <= w; q++){ 
    String bank = input.nextLine();
    //other codes here..
}
```

It is also questionable why you are reading the exact same file 10 times with your other loop.

Comment: The value array requires ten values with an undefined limit. The loop above resets the scanner to read the file from the beginning each time, and changes the element in the value array.